# Undefined Injected Service on ng-template outlet context

Tags: angular

I'm trying to pass a function that references an injected service to a button in the context of an outlet, but the injected service is undefined. Here is my code:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { MyService } from './my.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-my-component',
  template: `
    <ng-template
      [ngTemplateOutlet]="confirmTestingButton"
      [ngTemplateOutletContext]="{ buttonAction: action }">
    </ng-template>
    <ng-template #confirmTestingButton let-buttonAction="buttonAction">
      <button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm ml-5" (click)="buttonAction()">Yes</button>
    </ng-template>
  `
})
export class MyComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(public myService: MyService) { }

  ngOnInit() { }

  action() {
    this.myService.doSomething();
  }
}
```

Injected Service

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class MyService {
  constructor() {}

  doSomething() {
    // do something
  }
}
```

When I click the button, I get an error saying `Cannot read property 'doSomething' of undefined.` I'm not sure what's causing this. How can I fix this so that I can use the injected service inside the `action` function?

I tried to add the injected service in the context:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-my-component',
  template: `
    <ng-template
      [ngTemplateOutlet]="confirmTestingButton"
      [ngTemplateOutletContext]="{ buttonAction: action, myService: myService }">
    </ng-template>
    <ng-template #confirmTestingButton let-buttonAction="buttonAction" let-myService="myService">
      <button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm ml-5" (click)="buttonAction()">Yes</button>
    </ng-template>
  `
})
```

But still no luck. The only thing worked when I pass the service as a parameter of the button function, which is a bit awkward for me.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-my-component',
  template: `
    <ng-template
      [ngTemplateOutlet]="confirmTestingButton"
      [ngTemplateOutletContext]="{ buttonAction: action, myService: myService }">
    </ng-template>
    <ng-template #confirmTestingButton let-buttonAction="buttonAction" let-myService="myService">
      <button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm ml-5" (click)="buttonAction(myService)">Yes</button>
    </ng-template>
  `
})
export class MyComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(public myService: MyService) { }

  ngOnInit() { }

  action(myService: MyService) {
    myService.doSomething();
  }
}
```

Is there any proper approach on this?

Comment: Can you please provide your `my.service.ts` code?

Comment: @HardikSolanki I don't think it is relevant, but I updated the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using arrow function to maintain correct [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) context

```
action = () => { 
    this.myService.doSomething();
  }
```

**[Working Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-7qjpmj?file=src/app/app.component.html)**